# HTTP 500 error when iterating through arraylist of object in my JSP

Tags: class, jsp, tomcat, servlets, arraylist

I got this error: HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page when I tried to iterate an arraylist of an object (class defined by myself).

Here is the code in the jsp file

```
 <%
    class postClass{
        String username; //with username and postid, can go to edit to query for that exact post in database
        Integer postid;
        String title;
        Date modified;
        Date created;
        }
    %>
    <%
       ArrayList<postClass> list = (ArrayList<postClass>) request.getAttribute("list"); 

        for(postClass x : list) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    %>
```

And here's the error message

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:
type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP:

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 28 in the jsp file: /list.jsp
Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
25:     <%
26:        ArrayList<postClass> list = (ArrayList<postClass>) request.getAttribute("list"); 
27: 
28:        <% for(final postClass x : list) {
29:             out.println(x);
30:         } %>
31:
```

EDIT: updated code to answer below. still produces an error

Updated Error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:
type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP:

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [15] in the generated java file: [/var/lib/tomcat8/work/Catalina/localhost/editor/org/apache/jsp/list_jsp.java]
Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:199)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:450)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:361)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:564)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:401)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:345)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    Editor.doGet(Editor.java:238)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.14 (Debian) logs.
```

Comment: Add code as plain text, nobody is going to retype it to reproduce the issue. Please, read [MCVE] and try to improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

You have nested '<%' and '%>'. That is not allowed in jsp. Syntax error on tokens at line :28 denotes the '<%' token on line 28.

The correct code should be

```
<%
class postClass{
    String username; //with username and postid, can go to edit to query for that exact post in database
    Integer postid;
    String title;
    Date modified;
    Date created;
    }
%>
<%
   ArrayList<postClass> list = (ArrayList<postClass>) request.getAttribute("list"); 
   for(final postClass x : list) {
        out.println(x);
    }
%>
```

Note: This code will throw a null pointer exception if null is returned for `request.getAttribute("list")` . It is better to do a null check first.

Suggestion: Class names in java follow a convention of starting with a Capital letter. `postClass` should be renamed as `PostClass`

Answer (score 0):

You have a `<% ... ℅>` nested inside your java code. Delete these tokens, just as the error suggests.